# std::bind to a std::function crashes with Clang

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang

I'm having trouble understanding some subtleties when combining std::bind with std::function.

I have minimized my problems to the following code snippet:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void bar(int x) {
    std::cout << "Hello." << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::function<void(int)> f1 = std::bind(bar, std::placeholders::_1);

    // CRASHES with clang, works fine in VS2010 and VS2012
    std::function<void()> f2 = std::bind(f1, 1);

    f2();

    return 0;
}
```

Note the explicit conversion to std::function<> (replacing `std::function<void()>` with `auto` when constructing `f2` works fine).

Creating `f2` by copying the `f1` object crashes with Clang on OS X (XCode 5.0.1, OS X 10.9 SDK), but works fine with VS2010/VS2012. After a hideously long callstack, the code crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS - note this is when *constructing* the function object, not when calling it.

**Is this a bug in the library implementation or a problem with my code?**

A workaround is to explicitly call the `operator ()` member, like this:

```
std::function<void()> f2 =
    std::bind(&std::function<void(int)>::operator(), f1, 1);
```

but this comes with a caveat, as it fails to compile on VS2012 (but works in VS2010). This seems to be [a bug with VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842371/227322).

Comment: A related question seems to be http://stackoverflow.com/q/19820128/227322.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code works just fine with clang 3.4 (trunk, 194324).** It also works with gcc  4.7.2.

I don't get any warnings with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (except those that complain about the unused x, argc and argv parameters).

It seems as if the clang implementation was buggy in the past but has been fixed.

Comment: You are right, upgrading to Xcode 5.0.2 seems to do the trick.

Comment: @villintehaspam Glad to hear it!

Comment: A word of caution though, it seems that there is some kind of difference between XCode 5.0.2 downloaded from the App Store vs one downloaded from developer.apple.com. It works in the version downloaded from dev, but not in the one from the App Store.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac so... Do they have the exact same version number? Perhaps the one, in which it works, is slightly newer. (I am just guessing.)